# What battery should I use to power a solenoid?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-operated, solenoid, solenoid-valve

I’m quite new to electrical work and I’m trying to open and close a solenoid valve with a battery.

I have bought these tiny 23a 12 V batteries. The solenoid says it needs 12 VDC. I have no idea why it’s not opening; all I saw were some sparks.

The battery can output 55 mA  but other than that I can’t tell you much. If anyone could tell me what battery I should use it instead that would be great, as I wasted money on these batteries, and I don’t want to waste more money on other batteries that don’t work.

Comment: How much current does the solenoid need? My guess is that that poor 23a battery cannot deliver enough power. Maybe 8 AA batteries in series will do the job. Yes that's a lot of batteries but such a solenoid might need quite some power. If you have a 12 V power supply or a 12 V car battery, that would also work. 23a batteries are for low power applications like garage door remote control.

Comment: What do you mean how much current? Also, I was maybe thinking on buying like 2 9v batteries in series but I’m not sure.

Comment: 2 9V batteries in series give the wrong voltage and most probably wouldn't deliver enough current to switch the solenoid either. Well, maybe once, but not repeatedly.

Comment: *What do you mean how much current?* Look on the sticker on the solenoid, does it mention current or power? If the solenoid needs for example 1 A then the 55 mA (0.055A) of that 23a battery is **by far** not enough.

Comment: May I ask why 2 9v battery in series won't work? Shouldn't it output 18v and the solenoid uses 12? Why will it only work once? I'm going to activate the solenoid only for a brief second for more information.

Comment: The solenoid wants 12V, so 18V is too much; if the batteries manage to put through enough current (they are small, so probably not), the coil might fry. After one or two activations, the small 9V batteries wil probably be empty, even when they can deliver enough current to activate the solenoid.

Comment: Car battery. Assuming that works, measure the current it takes, and that'll let you work your way down from there.

Comment: https://www.ebaumsworld.com/jokes/they-walk-among-us/80444286/

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the size of the solenoid: that thing is meant to have a lot of power.

Your battery is not meant to provide a lot of power, at all.

This won't work.

You need a battery with higher current capacity. How much – hard to tell, but maybe the label or definitely the datasheet of the solenoid would tell you.

To test, use a 12 V power supply that is certainly able to drive this (a lab power supply, a car battery, …), and measure the hold current, and if you have an oscilloscope, also measure the turn on current.  Then you'll know what kind of current your battery needs to source, and then you can pick a battery.

Answer (score 2):

Those tiny batteries can't deliver the current the solenoid needs to activate. How much current it does need depends on the type of the solenoid; its datasheet will have that information.

You could try with 8 AA primary batteries in series, or 10 NiMH batteries in series, or a 12V sealed lead-acid battery, but for a definite answer we would need to know the specifications of the solenoid, and how often and for how long you plan to activate it.